# how to convert an array to a string after split function

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to convert the return value of the `.split()` function into a string.

There is a string of characters that is being parsed from a text file, and I need to change it from an array to a string.

After calling the split function, the result is an array, however, I need it to be a string to perform character operations and functions.

```
example = "--NAME: John Doe"
print example
value = example.split("--NAME: ")
print value.class
value.to_s.strip
print value
print value.class
```

Comment: It appears to me that you have a string (possibly read from a file, but that doesn't matter) and you wish to extract something from the string. If so, what do you want to extract? You need to tell us for your example (by editing your question). If I am correct, you should not assume that particular methods (e.g., `split`) are needed. Just say what you want  to achieve. This may be what's sometimes called an ["X-Y Problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Is `"--NAME: "` actually a _delimiter_? To me it looks more like a prefix / label.

Answer (score 1):

you can use '[join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join)' to convert the array to string.

With your example, I used 'join' to get string seperated by comma and used 'reject' to remove empty strings if any.

```
example = "--NAME: John Doe"
value = example.split("--NAME: ")
puts value
```

> ["", "John Doe"]

```
puts value.reject(&:blank?).join(",")
```

> "John Doe"

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=--NAME:)` Positive lookbehind assertion: ensures that the preceding characters match --NAME:, but doesn't include those characters in the matched text

`Strip!` to remove leading or trailing spaces in place.

```
irb(main):018:0>"--NAME: John Doe"[/(?<=--NAME:).*$/].strip!
```

Step by step:

```
irb(main):026:0> exampel = "--NAME: John Doe"
=> "--NAME: John Doe"
irb(main):027:0> example = exampel[/(?<=--NAME:).*$/].strip!
=> "John Doe"
irb(main):028:0> example
=> "John Doe"
irb(main):029:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `split()` isn't the right tool for your needs?

If you just want to remove the prompt you could try `gsub()` (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-gsub). `gsub()` stands for "global substitution" and in other languages it is often known as `replace()`.

`example.gsub("--NAME: ", "")`

Will replace the prompt with an empty string and give you:

> "John Doe"

(a String)

Answer (score 0):

Simply sub-string your string:

```
example = "--NAME: John Doe"

example[8..-1]

#=> "John Doe"
```

While `8` indicates the start position and `-1` indicates that the substring should be ended with the last character of the `example` string since the length of the `NAME` is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting your `example` string in same formats everytime,

```
example.split(' ', 2).last
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> value = example.split("--NAME: ")
#=> ["", "John Doe"]
> value.join.strip
#=> "John Doe"
```